# Como obter o resultado da query executada no Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Como faço para obter o resultado da `query` que será executada no banco de dados?

Exemplo:

```
foreach ($prestadores as $prestador){
  $achou = \DB::table('modulo_pr_espelho')
           ->where('prestador_id','=', $prestador->id)
           ->whereMonth('data_emissao',$mes)->get();
     if (!isset($achou)) {
           print "Prestador : " . $prestador->razao_social;
     }
}
```

Preciso saber como o `Eloquent` está montando esta `query`:

```
select modulo_pr_espelho.* where prestador_id = 1 where month(data_emissao) = 11
```

Qual o método que recupero o `select` puro que foi montado pelo `Eloquent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o metodo [toSql()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html) sobre o builder:

```
$achou = \DB::table('modulo_pr_espelho')
            ->where('prestador_id','=', $prestador->id)
            ->whereMonth('data_emissao',$mes)->toSql();
```

Desta maneira não tem acesso aos parametros da query (bindings), para conseguir o array com os parametros pode:

```
$achou = \DB::table('modulo_pr_espelho')
            ->where('prestador_id','=', $prestador->id)
            ->whereMonth('data_emissao',$mes)->getBindings();
```

Comment: funcionou obrigado!

Comment: De nada @MarceloGomes